# In Rails, How to parse a category and sub category url structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have my urls like:

```
www.example.com/categories/category1/subcategory1
```

My database would have a table Categories:

ID NAME        parentID
1 category1    -1
2 subcategory1 1

So I would need to load both category ID 1 and 2 since that is what is being displayed.

I know my explanation isn't that clear, but I hope what I am after is!

**OH, and how would this route be setup, since there could be an unlimited # of category/subcategory/sub-subcateogry  levels.**

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Following convention over configuration:

```
Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.
```

The rest of those guides are a good read.

Comment: but I want nested, unlimited nesting ability regardless of what convention dictates (in this case at least!)